# How to configure adb to listen on specific network interface?

Tags: android, security

My Android device has two network interfaces, one "public" and one "private". How to configure ADB (the Android Debug Bridge) to only listen on the "private" interface?
I know there is `service.adb.tcp.port` prop, and it works.
But an attempt to set `service.adb.tcp.ip` does not seem to have any effect...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

adbd listens on all interfaces and it cannot be configured right now, unfortunately.

Socket is created in [adb/daemon/main.cpp](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/master/adb/daemon/main.cpp#198) by calling `setup_port` with the port defined in the property "service.adb.tcp.port".
The function `setup_port` is defined [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/master/adb/daemon/main.cpp#145), which calls `local_init` defined [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/master/adb/transport_local.cpp#412), which basically calls `server_socket_thread` (defined [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/master/adb/transport_local.cpp#247)).
`server_socket_thread` calls `network_inaddr_any_server` until it succeeds.

The socket is finally created in the function `network_inaddr_any_server`, defined [there](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/master/libcutils/socket_inaddr_any_server_unix.cpp). We can see that [the address is hardcoded to zero](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/master/libcutils/socket_inaddr_any_server_unix.cpp#43), which means that it listens on all interfaces.

If you have a rooted device, it should be possible to add an iptables rule denying the port on the public interface. There are apps in the Play Store which install iptables.
The rule would be something like

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth1 -p tcp --dport 5555 -j DROP
```

where `eth1` is the public interface.

Or, you could also try to edit the function `network_inaddr_any_server`, compile adbd and replace it on your device, this requires root as well.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! So, this is true about any Android, not just  Android-x86 ?  This means that every time, when enabling `adb`,  I should turn off WiFi and LTE, right? I did not know about that... Specifically on Android-x86, it seems that `adb` is always on and there is no way to disable or turn it off...